# Consequence of restrictions in ontology on SPARQL end results

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantics, owl, ontology

I am concerned about two classes (SensingDevice and Property) of my ontology ([dgo.owl](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8b3rb66z045qt0/dgo.owl?dl=0)) as shown in the below figure. These two classes are connected by *observes* property:

[image]

and the related ontology portion is as:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#TemperatureSensor_Livingroom">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#SensingDevice"/>
  <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
      <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#observes"/>
      <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/qu/dim#Temperature"/>
    </owl:Restriction>
  </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

Now, using SPARQL query I want to know which property is observed by *TemperatureSensor_Livingroom* class, which is a subclass of *SensingDevice*. For the same I am using following query:

```sql
SELECT ?y 
WHERE {
    dgo:TemperatureSensor_Livingroom rdfs:subClassOf  ?p .
    ?p owl:allValuesFrom ?y .
}
```

With this query  I do get required result, but I do not understand that without using *observes* property how I am getting results? I tried to formulate different queries using *observes* property, but none of them results in required answer. I think in this case I am getting results with some trick, but I want to know the correct query for this case. I might be wrong, but I think restrictions are doing something in background that I am not able to get. Do these restrictions affect the way we should query?

**UPDATE:**
From the answers of Artemis and Chris, I found that in this case there is no good reason to use *observes* property directly in the SPARQL query becuase of the valid reasons provided in the mentioned answers. With this I found another related use case as:

[image]

Ontology is same (dgo.owl), only I have added some classes as depicted above.Now if I query for the same thing as mentioned in the previous case, i.e,

```
SELECT ?y 
WHERE {
dgo:TemperatureSensor_Livingroom rdfs:subClassOf  ?p .
?p owl:allValuesFrom ?y .}
```

As predicted it produces output as:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| x | y                                                  |
==========================================================
|   | dgo:PhysicalInput                                  |
|   | <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/qu/dim#Temperature>
```

In other words, it produces output related to two properties,i.e, *observes* and *detects*. In such a scenario, how can I get output related to *observes* property only.

Comment: You are not suppose to change your question, rather post another question. This is a bit confusing because of the people that will look at the questions in the future. Also, if you do so, you need to update the resources attached to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are querying the TBOX and `?p` in your query translates to the bnode representing the anonymous class restriction. You are not binding to instances in the query, but the value/class used for the `owl:allValuesFrom` restriction. So

`http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/qu/dim#Temperature`

would be the result of your query. Had you wanted to search for individuals that form the anonymous class, you would use the `observes` property. Looking at your data, you have not yet created any instances that use `observes`, so it is nowhere used apparently.

Comment: I agree with your point. But, in scenarios mentioned as **UPDATE** in question how to get intended answer.

Comment: Try: `SELECT ?y WHERE { dgo:TemperatureSensor_Livingroom rdfs:subClassOf  ?p . ?p owl:onProperty <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#observes>; owl:allValuesFrom ?y .}`

Answer (score 4):

If you write the following query:

```
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
    dgo:TemperatureSensor_Livingroom rdfs:subClassOf ?o.
    ?o ?p ?y.
}
```

You are extracting everything related to `dgo:TemperatureSensor_Livingroom` that is also a subclass of `?o`. If you look at the `?p` column, you can see that only `observers only temperature` is connected via **owl:allValuesFrom**. That is how is doesn't need to specify the type.

If you change your query to:

```
prefix dgo: <http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#>
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:subClassOf ?o.
    ?o owl:allValuesFrom ?y.
}
```

You can see that it again `observers only temperature` appears. So basically what I want to say is that the way you limits every member of a triple has a direct effect on what you extract on the next stage. Hope this helps!

Update 1:
Based on your updated query, you just need to name your intended object property in the query as well:

```
prefix dgo: <http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#>
prefix ssn: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    dgo:TemperatureSensor_Livingroom rdfs:subClassOf  ?p .
    ?p owl:allValuesFrom ?y .
    ?p owl:onProperty ssn:observes
}
```

Comment: Ok. Then how can Iresolve the case mentioned as UPDATE to given question.